# delphi tserversocket ignores 1st message

Tags: delphi, sockets, tcp

pls advise why this happens.
on a simple sample server app i have the following code:

```
procedure TForm13.ServerSocket1ClientRead(Sender: TObject;
Socket: TCustomWinSocket);
var str : string;
begin
  str := socket.ReceiveText;
  showmessage(str);
end;
```

and on the client side i have

```
clientsocket1.Open;
clientsocket1.Socket.SendText(txtMSG.Text);
```

nothing fancy.
the strange thing is that when i send a message to the server for 1st time it gets ignored. every time after that it works great. the ClientRead event doesn't fire off at all on the 1st message

what can i change on the server to make it accept the 1st message.
I have no control over the client side as a 3rd party sends me messages, ut i am always missing the 1st message.

thanks!

Comment: I recommend moving to Synapse or Internet Direct (Indy), the old socket components are deprecated since Delphi 6

Comment: @mjn: they were deprecated in D2009, not D6. And just because they are deprecated does not mean they cannot still be used or they are not still  useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using the `TClientSocket` in non-blocking mode (which is the default), you can't send data immediately after `Open()` returns, as the connection is not ready yet. You have to wait for the `OnConnect` event to be triggered first, eg:

```
Procedure TForm1.StartConnectingToServer;
Begin
  ClientSocket1.Open;
End;

Procedure TForm1.ClientSocket1Connect(Socket: TCustomWinSocket);
Begin
  Socket.SendText(txtMSG.Text);
End;
```

Comment: that explains a lot! unfortunately in the real world example i dont have control over the client side as it is a 3rd party system written by GE, and i dont see them making this code change for me any time soon

Comment: You don't have to worry about that. Your server code is fine (though in real world situations, `ReceiveText()` is rarely useful, you will use `ReceiveBuf()` a lot more often). Your problem was due to a bug in your test client trying to send data at the wrong time. People writing their own clients will deal with that same issue in their own way. It is not your responsibilty.